# Trying to render entity address from database with twig

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, twig

One user can add many addresses in the database. The address will be render in the same page that he added the address then he can choose which one he would like to use. Problem is it doesn't render anything but the address is save in the database.

This is my code:

```
PostController.php



public function validationAction()
{

}

public function addressAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
    $entity = new UserAddress();
    $form = $this->createForm(new UserAddressType(), $entity);
    if ($this->get('request')->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
              $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
              $entity->setUser($user);
              $em->persist($entity);
              $em->flush();

               return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('address'));
          }
      }
      return $this->render('FLYBookingsBundle:Post:address.html.twig', array('user' => $user,
            'form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

address.html.twig

```
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
            {% if user.address|length != 0 %}
            <div class="span4">

                <form action="{{ path('validation') }}" method="POST">
                    <h4>Billing address</h4>
                    {% for address in user.address %}
                    <label class="radio">
                        <input type="radio" name="address" value="{{ address.id }}" {% if loop.index0 == 0 %}checked="checked"{% endif %}>
                        {{ address.address }}, {{ address.zipcode }} {{ address.city }} - {{ address.country }} <a href="{{ path('AddressDelete', { 'id' : address.id }) }}"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
                        <br />{{ address.surname }} {{ address.name }}
                    </label>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Confirm my billing address</button>
                </form>

            </div>
            {% endif %}

            <div class="span4 offset2">
                <h4>Add a new billing address</h4>
                <form action="{{ path ('address') }}" method="POST">
                    {{ form_widget(form) }}
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**EDIT:**

```
User {#124 ▼
  #id: 21
  #facebook_id: null
  #facebook_access_token: null
  -commandes: null
  -address: null
  #createdAt: DateTime {#127 ▶}
  #updatedAt: DateTime {#126 ▶}
  #twoStepVerificationCode: null
  #dateOfBirth: null
  #firstname: null
  #lastname: null
  #website: null
  #biography: null
  #gender: "u"
  #locale: null
  #timezone: null
  #phone: null
  #facebookUid: null
  #facebookName: null
  #facebookData: null
  #twitterUid: null
  #twitterName: null
  #twitterData: null
  #gplusUid: null
  #gplusName: null
  #gplusData: null
  #token: null
  #username: "sirius"
  #usernameCanonical: "sirius"
  #email: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com"
  #emailCanonical: "XXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com"
  #enabled: true
  #salt: "tcng810acpww4gcg480s4ko0ssw8c4k"
  #password: "byEnk7zLFY2Y2ya9S0Vwk+hvwHEaoyYQyVzpxrtKjZJgHWplDSgdSqvw/PnAZ8Bu973udixrNOCALbghf68d9g=="
  #plainPassword: null
  #lastLogin: DateTime {#128 ▶}
  #confirmationToken: null
  #passwordRequestedAt: null
  #groups: PersistentCollection {#105 ▶}
  #locked: false
  #expired: false
  #expiresAt: null
  #roles: []
  #credentialsExpired: false
  #credentialsExpireAt: null
}
```

Comment: what is the error message please ?

Comment: there is no any error message. it doens't render anything that is inside of this block : ` {% if user.address|length != 0 %} {% endif %}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{% for data in user %}
  {% if data.address|length != 0 %}
     /.. Blabla ../
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i tried with your example, it still doesn't work.  Do you think maybe there is a problem in my addressAction ?

Comment: I don't really know. Try to dump user in your template: `{{ dump(user) }}` and have a look to the result to see what kind of data are passed to the template. Maybe, it's a simple typo, maybe something else... :)

Comment: You can check on top [EDIT:]  my  {{ dump(user) }} result.

Comment: `address: null` . It seems your template has the good behavior :)

Comment: i can also see that is `address: null` . what should i do to fix it ?

Comment: You want to display address(es) but it/they don't yet exist in DB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101192/discussion-between-sirius-and-scoolnico).