# Doctrine and Symfony2 : Association refers to inverse side that doesn't exist error

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a page address.html.twig , the user can add many addresses in the table UserAddress. when he added his address in the database , the address should be render in the same page that he added his address then he can choose which one he would like to use. Unfortunately the address is not render.

First i thought that i have a problem in my controller action or in my twig page. I even asked a question here about it =>  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900915/trying-to-render-entity-address-from-database-with-twig)

I verified all my tables in phpmyadmin and all of them are well link but if i'm doing this: php app/console doctrine:schema:validate 
i have this error :

> [Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class
>   'FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Commandes' mapping is invalid:
>   * The association FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Commandes#user refers to the inverse side field
>   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User#commandes which does not
>   exist.
>
> [Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class
>   'FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\UserAddress' mapping is invalid:
>   * The association FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\UserAddress#user refers to the inverse side field
>   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User#address which does not
>   exist.

Have a look at this picture:

[image]

This is my UserAddress.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="address")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $user;
```

Commandes.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="commandes")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $user;
```

User.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FLY\UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */


    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->commandes = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->address = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Commandes", mappedBy="user", cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $commandes;



    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\UserAddress", mappedBy="user", cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $address;
```

Here you can see my var dump:

```
User {#124 ▼
  #id: 21
  -commandes: null
  -address: null
}
```

Comment: This is possibly a namespacing error. How can User have a repository class of @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FLY\UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository") but according to Commandes the user entity is in Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User - it seems unlikely the repository would be generated in a separate bundle. Thoroughly check you have your mappings pointing to the correct namespaces for your entities.

Answer (score 1):

I've had an issue which has popped up 2-3 times in the last few years, where the mappings were incorrect but the schema update was successful. After the mappings were fixed this wasn't reflected in the schema and symfony assumed it was already up-to-date.

I recommend you try removing the relevent relationships manually from your user, commande and address tables and then run:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

- it may fix your issue.

Comment: Sorry for the delay response. i removed the relationship manually in (user, commandes, UserAddress) after update --force and schema validate i don't get any error. But i still want my table to be link because i need to render some details about the user like address and commandes.

Comment: Once you ran the command it would of recreated the foreign keys links

Comment: Thank for your help :) This morning i found a way to solved my problem. I wrote the relationship in my user.php but it wasn't working so i decided to make the relationship in this file :  `Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\User.orm.xml` and it works perfectly my addresses are render as i wanted. This is what i did : 
`<one-to-many field="address" target-entity="FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Address" mapped-by="user">
</one-to-many>
<one-to-many field="commandes" target-entity="FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Commandes" mapped-by="user">
</one-to-many>`

Comment: I'm upvoting you, although in my situation it didn't fix the issue (not yet at least), but I believe using this tool helps sanitizing the Doctrine schema that's being stored. I found some troubles with manual updates I applied but the schema not being updated. Now, thanks to the errors that this tool highlights (SQL errors, with an ALTER pointing that the Entity has a field as NOT NULL when it should be NULL, for instance).

Comment: Thanks @JasonButler finally this was definitively helpful. As I said, it didn't fix my issue but it helped sanitizing changes I had manually applied.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example from one of my apps - I've done this for your commandes entity.
You'll be able to piece together your UserAddress Entity from this example yourself!

Here goes:

User.php

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Commandes", mappedBy="commandesUser")
 */
protected $commandes;
```

User.php - Getters and Setters

```
/**
 * Add commandes
 *
 * @param FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Commandes $commandes
 */
public function addCommandes(\FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Commandes $commandes)
{
    $this->commandes[] = $commandes;
}

/**
 * Get commandes
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getCommandes()
{
    return $this->commandes;
}
```

Commandes.php

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="commandes")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $commandesUser;
```

Commandes.php - Getters and Setters

```
/**
 * Set commandesUser
 *
 * @param Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User $commandesUser
 */
public function setCommandesUser(\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User $commandesUser = null)
{
    $this->commandesUser = $commandesUser;
}

/**
 * Get $commandesUser
 *
 * @return Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
 */
public function getCommandesUser()
{
    return $this->commandesUser;
}
```

Comment: i tried with your code but still doesn't work: `* The association FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Commandes#commandesUser refers to the inverse side field Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User#commandes which does not exist.`

Answer (score 0):

It's quite likely this doesn't happen to anyone else, but there's a chance.

In my case, this error appeared because there was a duplicate. My entity had 2 fields, which are `ManyToOne` relationships. And they both had the same inversed names, which gave this error.

So this is the relevant bit of code:

```
class TaskIngredient
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Ingredient", inversedBy="taskIngredients")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $ingredient;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Task", inversedBy="taskIngredients")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $task;
}
```

The solution was relatively easy. I tried changing the `inversedBy` name, manually. However this didn't fix it (even after applying `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` and removing the `var/cache` folder).

So I just:

1. Removed one of the problematic entities (and it's setter/getter)
2. Ran the `php bin/console make:entity` tool and readded the field with a different name
3. Voilà! Issue fixed.